# View not updating after orientation change

Tags: java, android, landscape

I have an Adapter class `MyAdapter` -

```
 @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        viewHolder.time.setText(strText);
        viewHolder.time.setTextColor(0xff000000);
        viewHolder.time.setTextSize(17);
        viewHolder.time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.time.setBackgroundColor(nColor);
        viewHolder.time.setPadding(25,25,25,25);
        MyFragment my= new MyFragment();
        my.setLandScape1(strText,nColor);
        view.invalidate();
        }
    }
```

In `MyFragment`,

```
public void setLandScape1(String time1,int time_Bcolor1){
    this.delay_time1 = time1;
    this.delay_time_BColor1 = time_Bcolor1;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("Time",delay_time1);
    outState.putInt("BColor",delay_time_BColor1);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
       delay_time1 = savedInstanceState.getString("Time");
        Log.d("hi","delay_time1 = " + delay_time1);
        delay_time_BColor1 = savedInstanceState.getInt("BColor");
        Log.d("hi","delay_time_BColor1  =" + delay_time_BColor1);
    } }
```

The logs are -

When turned horizontal,

```
delay_time1 = 45

delay_time_BColor1  = 65000
```

Again when turned vertical,

```
 delay_time1 = 0

delay_time_BColor1  = 0
```

Why it becomes `0` when turned to portrait and why in landscape though, I am getting values in `onCreate()`, still view is not updating.

Answer (score 0):

Move the logic from `onCreate` to `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Once the view is recreated, `onRestoreInstanceState` will be called and not `onCreate()`

Comment: Ok but I am not able to Override onRestoreInstanceState() in MyFragment class. What could be the reason

Comment: You can use onActivityCreated() in fragment to restore, but this is not consisted design. You should design the activity to handle orientation changes.

Comment: Oh.. I tried in onActivityCreated(), the app is crashing